# automatically go to the result page after pressing save button

Tags: android, eclipse

how do I make it automatically go to the result page after I press the save button? my application seems to stay on the same page after I press the save button. attached below is the source code

DetailForm.Java

```
public class DetailForm extends Activity {
EditText name = null;
EditText address = null;
EditText telephone = null;
EditText details = null;
NameCardHelper helper = null;
String namecardId = null;
TextView location = null;
LocationManager locMgr = null;
double latitude = 0.0d;
double longitude = 0.0d;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_form);

    locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    helper = new NameCardHelper(this);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    telephone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telephone);
    details = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.details);
    location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);

    namecardId = getIntent().getStringExtra(NameCardList.ID_EXTRA);
    if (namecardId != null) {
        load();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    save();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    helper.close();
    locMgr.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.details_option, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (namecardId == null) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.location).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.map).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return (super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.location) {

        locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                onLocationChange);
        return (true);

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.map) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, NameCardMap.class);
            i.putExtra(NameCardMap.EXTRA_LATITUDE, latitude);
            i.putExtra(NameCardMap.EXTRA_LONGITUDE, longitude);
            i.putExtra(NameCardMap.EXTRA_NAME, name.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
            return (true);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.call) {
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                String p = "tel:" + telephone.getText();
                i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
                startActivity(i);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.sms) {

            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + telephone.getText()));
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete) {

            helper.delete(namecardId);

            startActivity(new Intent(this, NameCardList.class));
            return (true);
        }
    return true;
        }

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (info != null);
}

private void load() {
    Cursor c = helper.getById(namecardId);
    c.moveToFirst();

    name.setText(helper.getName(c));
    address.setText(helper.getAddress(c));
    telephone.setText(helper.getTelephone(c));
    details.setText(helper.getDetails(c));

    latitude = helper.getLatitude(c);
    longitude = helper.getLongitude(c);
    location.setText(String.valueOf(latitude) + ", "
            + String.valueOf(longitude));

    c.close();
}

private void save() {
    if (name.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

        if (namecardId == null) {
            helper.insert(name.getText().toString(), address.getText()
                    .toString(), telephone.getText().toString(),
                    details.getText().toString());
        } else {
            helper.update(namecardId, name.getText().toString(), address
                    .getText().toString(), telephone.getText().toString(),
                    details.getText().toString());
        }
    }

}

LocationListener onLocationChange = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location fix) {
        helper.updateLocation(namecardId, fix.getLatitude(),
                fix.getLongitude());
        location.setText(String.valueOf(fix.getLatitude()) + ", "
                + String.valueOf(fix.getLongitude()));
        locMgr.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);

        Toast.makeText(DetailForm.this, "Location saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Where is the save button listener????

Comment: Where have you defined or initialize your save button in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Say your result page is named ResultActivity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

  startActivity(intent);
```

make sure result activity is in Manifest :) ... use above code in save button click listener

Daniel is correct you need to set click listener first of all for the save button, say "btn" is the id of your Button in xml.

```
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);   
  btn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: That's ok, but he needs a listener for the save button for calling the result activity.

Comment: I think I dun have the save intent on my source code.. where can I put the save intent? sorry to trouble u guys :)

Comment: you can add the clicklistener containing the intent/startactivity code in oncreate method of your activity..

Answer (score 0):

Where is your save button? There doesn't appear to be any reference to it.

You need to either have a public method that you talk to from your button in your xml (via onClick)  or you need to add a click callback to your button in your source.  You don't seem to be doing either, so, if you have a button in your XML it's not attached to any action, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given onClick in the xml page i.e. android:Onclick="save" for that button then it works or else you can bind the button in the activity class and add action listener to it